# Replace exact matching string

Tags: c#

I want to dynamically replace an exact sub string from a string. For ex I want to replace `"dis.[Test Table]"` to `"dbo.[Test Table]"` in the following string:

> SELECT        Name FROM            dis.[Test Table].

Note that I it could be any text and any sub string. It will replace only exactly matched sub string as many times as it will occur.

Comment: Why not simply use the built in `String.Replace`? It does exactly what you describe...

Answer (score 0):

use String.Replace() Method

```
fullString = fullString.Replace("oldSubString", "newSubString");
```

Just to elaborate further, your example can be written as:

```
var newString = "SELECT Name FROM dis.[Test Table]".Replace("dis.[Test Table]","dbo.[Test Table]");

// newString will become "SELECT Name FROM dbo.[Test Table]"
```

More details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Can't use the built in .Replace function. Because that would also replace dis.[Test Table1] which is not the exact match. Even tried Regex Replace. But that didn't worked either.

Comment: I would recommend `fullString = fullString.Replace("oldSubString", "newSubString");` because it actually doesn't replace the string, but returns a new one.

Comment: @R.Azmi Replace() will work with exact match, It will not replace **dis.[Test Table1]** Have a look here at working example https://dotnetfiddle.net/K5bqYK

Comment: Thank you @JeroenvanLangen. That's true. Answer edited (Y).